# unable to use cdkDropConnectedTo property in library

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

below is my code that i have added it in my html for drag and drop functionality in my project folder. that is i have created library using cli command `ng generate library some-lib`

```
    <div cdkDropList cdkDrop  [cdkDropConnectedTo]="otherProgramItems" [cdkDropData]="progItem.items" (cdkDropListDropped)="droppedMenu($event)">
        <div class="progressLabel">{{progItem.name}}</div>
        <input class="taskName" [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" (keyup.enter)="creatingTask(progItem.name)"/>
        <div class="tasks" cdkDrag *ngFor="let tasks of progItem.items; let i = index">
            <span class="task-pointer" (click)="editMode=true;currentOpenIndex=i" *ngIf="!editMode || (editMode && currentOpenIndex !== i)">{{tasks.name}}</span>
            <input *ngIf="editMode && currentOpenIndex===i" (blur)="editMode=false;currentOpenIndex=null;saveChange();" (keyup.enter)="editMode=false;currentOpenIndex=null;saveChange();" type="text" [(ngModel)]="tasks.name"/>
            <mat-icon class="delete" (click)="deleteFromArray(progItem.items,i)" >delete</mat-icon></div>
    </div>
```

the above code gits the error as 
Can't bind to 'cdkDropConnectedTo' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
as well as Can't bind to 'cdkDropData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Below is my modile.ts file inside lib folder

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TileComponent } from './tile/tile.component';
import {
  DragDropModule
} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TileComponent],
  imports: [
    DragDropModule
  ],
  exports: [TileComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably made a typo in the template. There is no `cdkDropConnectedTo` directive property, but there is `cdkDropListConnectedTo`...

Comment: YEs . actually i followed this link.https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290